# What is the Three.Face3 in viewer.impl.hitTestViewport returned object?

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

What is the Three.face in the object returned by `viewer.impl.hitTestViewport()`?

Here's an example:

[image]

What does it represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look at the source code in the [three.js viewer implementation](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/three.js) at line #8228.

```
// File:src/core/Face3.js

  /**
   * @author mrdoob / http://mrdoob.com/
   * @author alteredq / http://alteredqualia.com/
   */

  THREE.Face3 = function ( a, b, c, normal, color, materialIndex ) {

    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;

    this.normal = normal instanceof THREE.Vector3 ? normal : new THREE.Vector3();
    this.vertexNormals = normal instanceof Array ? normal : [];

    this.color = color instanceof THREE.Color ? color : new THREE.Color();
    this.vertexColors = color instanceof Array ? color : [];

    this.vertexTangents = [];

    this.materialIndex = materialIndex !== undefined ? materialIndex : 0;

  };

  THREE.Face3.prototype = {

    constructor: THREE.Face3,

    clone: function () {

      var face = new THREE.Face3( this.a, this.b, this.c );

      face.normal.copy( this.normal );
      face.color.copy( this.color );

      face.materialIndex = this.materialIndex;

      for ( var i = 0, il = this.vertexNormals.length; i < il; i ++ ) {

        face.vertexNormals[ i ] = this.vertexNormals[ i ].clone();

      }

      for ( var i = 0, il = this.vertexColors.length; i < il; i ++ ) {

        face.vertexColors[ i ] = this.vertexColors[ i ].clone();

      }

      for ( var i = 0, il = this.vertexTangents.length; i < il; i ++ ) {

        face.vertexTangents[ i ] = this.vertexTangents[ i ].clone();

      }

      return face;

    }

  };
```

Take also a look at the three.js [Face3](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Face3) documentation:

> Triangular face used in Geometry. These are created automatically for all standard geometry types, however if you are building a custom geometry you will have to create them manually.

Comment: What is the purpose of returning it from `hitTestViewport`? What is it used for in this case?

Comment: That's just the Face3 entity being intersected. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer that off-hand. What I can say with certainty, however, is how to implement ray tracing in the viewer, i.e., how to define a ray to be shot and how to determine the three.js objects intersected by it in the Forge model. This is demonstrated by the ForgeFader project on GitHub:

https://github.com/jeremytammik/forgefader

Comment: It would be nice to know what that face is, maybe I could use it for something.